# Best practice in deleting records in Laravel? PhpStorm throws warning

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

When writing the following code in PhpStorm it warns "Unhandled \Exception":

```
Flight::where('flight_number', $flight_number)->delete();
```

This is pretty much exactly how it's documented on Laravel's website. I don't believe this throws an error if no records are found to be deleted?

Should this really be wrapped in a try/catch, with an empty catch since it's not really an error? Especially since in my instance it's fine if no records are found to be deleted.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden well I tagged both PHPStorm and Laravel. The inspection in PHPStorm only happens with Laravel.

Comment: Is `flight_number` a primary key?

Comment: I think this is because somewhere in the stack an error can be thrown. Now the question is why? Probably because you can try to select a record that does not exist and then try to delete it. This can also happen as a race condition between 2 users deleting a record. So yes it might be better to handle these situations.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden nope. And PHPStorm warns about this no matter how I call the ->delete() method. Seems to always think I should be catching an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PhpStorm warns you for a simple reason. The docblock of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::delete()` contains this [`@throws \Exception` annotation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L764):

```
/**
 * Delete the model from the database.
 *
 * @return bool|null
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function delete()
```

PhpStorm doesn't care how you call `delete()` or if `flight_number` is the `PK` of the table or not. It couldn't know these things. All it knows is the `@throws` annotation mentioned above and it tries to be useful by reminding you this thing.

You can ignore the warning, disable it for the entire project (in Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Error handling -> Unhandled exception) or you can disable it only for the statement that calls the `delete()` method.

For this last option you can put:

```
/** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection */
```

on a separate line just before the `delete()` call. This is a special docblock annotation that tells PhpStorm to ignore the unhandled exceptions that could be thrown by the statement that follows it.

Alternatively, you can put the caret on the `delete()` call, press <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd> and choose "Add @throws tag" -> "Suppress for statement" from the context menu that opens. It will add the comment for you.

This is the best way if you know for sure that `delete()` won't throw any exception (it throws when the model is not properly defined; this is not a runtime error but a coding error; it must never happen after the model was coded).

Another way to silence it is to add the `@throws \Exception` annotation in the docblock of the function that contains the call to `delete()`. This lets PhpStorm know that the exception is not handled at this level and, of course, it will warn you if you don't handle the exception in the code that calls this function.

Comment: Small addition (for OP/other users who will face the same situation): try not to pollute your code with error suppression comments that are IDE specific -- it does not look nice (useless) for other IDE/editors users + overall ("hey, instead of handling he ignores it" kind of thoughts that quite likely will appear  when reading code with such comments).

Comment: P.S. (general info) Inspection can also be suppressed on per file basis if needed (by using custom scope) -- that's an alternative to disabling it for the whole project. It may be annoying in one place (so you turn it off) but very useful in another -- better than not having it at all...

Comment: The exception likely _is_ handled by the framework exception handler (caught logged, error page rendered) higher up the stack. That's appropriate in the case of a misconfigured model so you dont need to catch it.  it's just too hard for PHPstorm to realise this is the case.